# Why does Schlick's approximation contain a \$(1-\cos\theta)^5\$ term?

Tags: lighting, mathematics

[The approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlick%27s_approximation) writes the reflection coefficient as$$R(\theta)=R_0+(1-R_0)(1-\cos\theta)^5,\,R_0=\left(\frac{n_1-n_2}{n_1+n_2}\right)^2.$$Why is the exponent 5? [Schlick 1994](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~jdl/bib/appearance/analytic%20models/schlick94b.pdf) introduces this exponent in Eq. (24), claiming it's the right Fresnel approximation, but with no explanation.

Comment: Before equation 15, they have several constraints. I guess they extended those a bit further in order to get a higher continuity at $F_{\lambda}^{(k)}(1) = 0$.

Comment: @lightxbulb Thanks. An exponent of $3$ or $4$ would meet the stated conditions, but I suspect $5$ was obtained either with an approximation of (13) or empirical trial & error.

Comment: Just plug in a larger $k$ in what I wrote, and you'll get the higher degree.

Comment: @lightxbulb I understand the calculus, but such conditions have no motive apparent in the paper.